# Meteor.js event handler: DB & CSS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have the following event handler in a Meteor app:

```
Template.messageItem.events({
'click .message-block #faveMsg': function (e) {
    console.log($(e.target));
    if (_.contains(this.favoritedBy, Meteor.userId())) {
        Messages.update({_id: this._id}, {$pull: {favoritedBy: Meteor.userId()} });
        $(e.target).removeClass('selected');
    } else{
        Messages.update({_id: this._id}, {$addToSet: {favoritedBy: Meteor.userId() } });
        $(e.target).addClass('selected');
    };
    console.log(this.favoritedBy);
    // $(e.target).toggleClass('selected');
}
});
```

The CSS update works independently. As soon as I bring in db logic the CSS change stops working.

I previously had a single toggleClass method (commented out above) which did the job but that no longer works if I reinstate it while commenting out the add/remove methods currently being used... ie something broke after I added the DB logic.

I'm guessing this is a dumb JS syntax issue as I'm a js newb... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm nearly certain this is happening:

1. You update a document.
2. You change the css on the rendered version of that document.
3. The server receives the update (1), and sends a new version of the document to the client.
4. The document (or possibly more things) is rendered again on your page.

The trouble is that (4) invalidates any changes that were made in (2) because the DOM element is removed from the page and a new version is added back. The best way to deal with this in the current version of meteor is to use a session variable which stores the id of the message. You can then use that session variable to render the right version of the css. So instead of your `$(e.target)...` you could do:

```
Session.set('selectedMessage', this._id);
```

Then you can add a template helper like this:

```
Template.messageItem.helpers({
  selected: function() {
    return Session.equals('selectedMessage', this._id);
  }
});
```

Finally, your template code could use that helper to display the right class:

```
<div class='{{selected}}'>{{message.text}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks David! I think you've hit the nail on the head with the re-render causing the issue. Rather than the session variable & helper method I solved it by specifying a #constant region in my HTML

Answer (score 0):

Building on David's observation above the DB update was causing my template to re-render (I should have realized as that is standard behavior in Meteor...). So the cleanest solution I could find was to wrap the relevant HTML element in a constant block:

```
<span class="speech-left-title">
  {{#constant}}
    <i id="faveMsg" class="fa fa-star"></i>
  {{/constant}}
    Received from {{sentBy}} {{timeago sentTime}}.
</span>
  {{#if msgTypeText}}
  <p class="speech-left blue-bubble">{{msgText}}</p> 
  ...
```

Subsequently when my JS function updates the DB & adds the 'selected' class to the icon element Meteor doesn't re-render it and it preserves my selected-element CSS

Comment: Yep, that looks good. I didn't realize from the question that the element you were updating didn't have any bindings and therefore could be made a constant. I suspect that when the new version of the rendering engine comes out (should be in 0.8), I don't think this step will be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is take out the CSS class insert from the event handler and put conditional logic in the html/handlebars code:

```
  <span class="speech-left-title">
    {{#if favoritedByMe}}
      <i id="faveMsg" class="fa fa-star selected"></i>
    {{else}}
      <i id="faveMsg" class="fa fa-star"></i>
    {{/if}}
    Received from {{sentBy}} {{timeago sentTime}}.
  </span>
```

This reactively updates the element and also works well. The downside of this approach is that it simply re-renders the html icon element when it is favorited rather than just adding a class, so you lose CSS transitions. However you avoid the constant block which could cause issues in some use cases